# Algorithm Complexity-Nested For Loops

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, code-complexity

```
for(j=n; j>1; j/=2)
  ++p;
for(k=1; k<p; k*=2)
    ++q;
```

On the first code sample, *p* variable belong to *1st* loop. So,even they are not nested loop,will *2nd* return **log(n)**,too? I mean totally, **O(loglog(n))**?

```
for(i=n; i>0; i--){
  for(j=1; j<n; j*=2){
    for(k=0; k<j; k++){
      //statements-O(1)
    }
  }
}
```

And these one, they are nested but *k* variable belong to *2nd* loop. So, should it similar to 1st one? Like **O(n^2.log(n))** or *O(n.log^2(n))*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find time complexity of an algorithm](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11032015/how-to-find-time-complexity-of-an-algorithm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Algorithm:
   First loop takes log(n) time. Second loop takes log(log(n)) time. So you have log(n) + log(log(n)). But first loop counts more. So it's **O(log(n))**.
2. Algorithm: At first look what runtime you have when you only analyse the two outer for loops (means n log(n)). But unfortunately there comes an inner third for loop which makes it more complex.

   The third for loop counts from 0 to 2^m where m=log(n). So you have to sum 2^m from 0 to log(n)-1 which is n-1. So n-1 is the run time of the two inner for loops. Now you have to multiply it by the linear run time of the outer for loop. So it's (n-1)n which is n²-n. So you have **O(n²)** for the three loops.

Comment: Thank you. Now i understand that return value and runtime's difference for 1st quesstion.